# Hide div on mouseout

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two  say 'DIV A' and 'DIV B'. On mouse over of DIV A, DIV B should be visible and remains displaying. DIV B contains few links. Now I need to hide DIV B on mouseout of this DIV B. How to fix this?

Comment: share your code pleaseeeeeeeeeee...

Comment: Check out JQuery, google and read. Thousands of example online

Comment: Really broad and non-research efforts. Please share what have you done. And we will surely help you.

Comment: you want your whole assignment without doing any efforts?

Comment: Not like that. I am new to these kind of stuff... Just need suggestions. Thats it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have fiddled the code try it.

using jquery

```
var diva = $('div.a'),
    divb = $('div.b')
divb.hide();
diva.on('mouseover', function(){
    divb.show();
});
diva.on('mouseout', function(){
    divb.hide();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6fff9/1/

Comment: But when you mouse out the red box the blue box disappears. What i need is when i do a mouse out of blue box it should hide. Is it possible

Comment: just play with it you will get it. I have made just small correction. http://jsfiddle.net/6fff9/3/

Answer (score 3):

**CSS only solution** (assuming both divs are in a div)

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/4p8CM/1995/)**</kbd>

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="divA">DIV A</div>
    <div class="divB">DIV B</div>
</div>
```

css

```
#container > div {
    display: none
}
#container > div:first-child {
    display: block
}
#container:hover > div {
    display: block
}
.divA{
    background:red;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
.divB{
    background:green;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. You have given me 50% answer.

Comment: whats 50% other problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<div id="DIVA" onmouseover="show_div()">First Div</div>
<div id="DIVB" onmouseout="hide_div()" style="display:none">Second Div</div>
<script>
    function show_div() {
      $(DIVB).show();

    }
    function hide_div() {
      $(DIVB).hide();
   }
 </script>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: Please feel free to mark as answer if i satisfies,Regards..

Answer (score 0):

Try this :)

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#div-a').mouseenter(function(){
            $('#div-b').show();
        });
        $('#div-b').mouseout(function(){
            $(this).hide();
        });
    });
</script>

<div id='div-a' style='background-color: #ccc'>Div A</div>
<div id='div-b' style='margin-top: 5px; background-color: #888; display: none'>Div B</div>
```